# How to use multiple alfresco AMP file in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, alfresco-share

I have created one Alfresco project in Eclipse. I want to use one uploader-plus AMP file in my newly created Alfresco project in Eclipse.

How can I achieve this?

can we use multiple amps in single alfresco project in eclipse or can we create single amp file by combining 2 different amp files???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Independently from the IDE you are using, it is possible to setup an All-In-One project to fetch and apply several extra amps before starting up (either from a local or a remote maven repo) :

- Create a new amp (Optional)
- Build a release for your amp (Optional)
- Add dependency for your amp in your project (You may need to add a repository as well)
- Add an overlay for your amp to either share or repo (depending on the nature of your amp)
- Run and enjoy

To learn more about this process please check the official documentation [here](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/alfresco-sdk-advanced-add-custom-amps.html)

---

**UPDATE :** In the case of `uploader-plus` amps, you need either to fetch projects from [here](https://github.com/softwareloop/uploader-plus) and install them locally (using `mvn clean install`) or add reference in your pom to this maven repo :
`https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/` but I can see only v1.2 is released [there](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/softwareloop/uploader-plus-repo/) so you probably would want to stick to option 1 !

Comment: Hi younes,  can you tell me tho location of third party amp's.  where should i put those third party amp's that i wanted to use in my current project??

Comment: they need to be installed in some m2 repo! either your local m2 repo or a remote one, in case you of a remote one (google docs integration / RM module for example), it should be added to your pom.xml

Comment: ok, thanks     But what is exact path in m2.  means where should i need to put that amp in me repo.  in my case i am using uploader plus amp.  i also added dependency in pom.xml. But when i run the project i am getting error.  please help.  Thanks in advance