# Refer custom alfresco content Content Model in maven project

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-maven

I am using the alfresco repo archetype maven project (alfresco maven SDK 2.1.1) and have a custom alfresco content model defined. In my custom alfresco content model, I need to use/refer an aspect defined in another alfresco content model from a separate amp.

Can anyone please advise what is the correct methodology how achieving the above described?

**Note**
I can add the custom content model xml file to the maven project and bootstrap it but I am more after a cleaner method keeping in mind module dependency management when doing a release of my amps.

Any help much appreciated.

Regards,
Kavi

Comment: Mark one amp as depending on the other in the module properties, then import the namespace of one content model in the other?

Answer (score 1):

In order to have one AMP depend on another you have to use the all-in-one archetype. You can then add the AMPs your project depends on with an overlay, see [How to use multiple alfresco AMP file in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36257155/how-to-use-multiple-alfresco-amp-file-in-eclipse/36260913)